# How to Float left the group of images that are on the right side of the picture in HTML & CSS code?

Tags: html, css

[image]

How can i position the right side image box `(box-2)` after the left side image box`(box-1)` when the device is less then `600px` width `(for Mobile and Tablet devices)` in `HTML` and `CSS` coding?

HTML code:

```
<div class="container_12 bot-1 lp">

    <div id="l" >
    <ul>
    <li >
                <img src="images/page3-img1.jpg" alt="">         
              </li>

             <li>
                <img src="images/page3-img3.jpg" alt="">         
              </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div  >
    <ul id="rid">
         <li >
          <img src="images/page3-img2.jpg" alt="" >         
        </li>

 <li>
          <img src="images/page3-img4.jpg" alt="">         
        </li>

    </ul>
    </div>
```

Please Help me someone how can i do this.

Comment: Do you have any code for this

Comment: share your code, its not helping much

Answer (score 1):

put your css in :

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
       div,ul{float:left;}
     }
```

Comment: hi @riva , i've done that but it's not working. what will be the css code inside the `@media( ....){ }` ?

Answer (score 0):

Set image Box size `600px`

```
(box-1) css = float:left; width:45%;
(box-1) css= float:left; width:45%;
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others use the css `@media (max-width: 600px)`

Here is an example:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bk29vau1/)

Also don't forget to use this in your `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Please try with this

 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-width: 768px) {

  .box1,.box2{
    float:left;
    width:48%
   }

}
```

Comment: Not an answer, It should be a comment.

Comment: Corrected the comment @Maddy